# How to print graph without scope

Tags: matlab, simulink

My Simulink model:

[image]

Is it possible to print this graph without scope (in matlab code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can save the data to the workspace using a [To Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) block and plot it after the simulation has finished using standard MATLAB code. Plenty more options in the doc under [Visualize Results](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/visualize-results.html).

Answer (score 0):

Rightklick on a Signal->Create connected viewer->Floating scope.

If you need more advanced techniques, check the documentation examples about signal logging and signal inspection.